# Variável da controller fica nula no get do ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho um `List` de objetos que é instanciada quando a view é criada, quando um valor no dropdownlist é selecionado, uso `ajax` para fazer um request pra verificar qual dos objetos dentro daquele `List` é o correspondente do dropdownlist. O problema é que esse `List` fica nulo no método do `ajax`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    List<Lanche> lanches = new List<Lanche>();

    ...

    public IActionResult Index()
    {    
        PopularListaLanches(lanches);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetIngredientes")]
    public JsonResult GetIngredientes(int id)
    {
        var lanche = lanches.Where(x => (int)x.NomeLanche == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(lanche);
    }
```

existe uma maneira de persistir esses dados na sessão do usuário?

Comment: *"existe uma maneira de persistir esses dados na sessão do usuário?"*  A sua pergunta já responde a dúvida :-)

Comment: Você pode colocar na sessão: `Session["lanches"] = lanches`.
Uma outra solução, se a lista for a mesma para todos os usuários usar cache ou até transformar a lista em estática: `static List<Lanche> lanches = new List<Lanche>();`

Comment: O ideal seria o seu modelo buscar o item quando necessário, usar Session é uma ideia, mas não seria melhor buscar esse valor somente quando ele fosse necessário?